# Run a job in datastage when the input is empty

Tags: etl, datastage

At work we're using Datastage 9.1 to create some reports, the basic structure is a JOB that uses an Oracle Connector to SELECT the data we need and then creates some reports using transformers.
The thing is, when there are 0 records the JOB simply skips everything and goes to create an empty output file EVEN if the transformer has some "hard coded" data, this means that some parts of the report have static data that will always be there, some strings and the such.
Is there any way we can force DS to run through the whole JOB even if there are no inputs? Thanks.

As a follow up, I thought about creating a select that will always return at least a value, something like a "SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, '1' AS DATA FROM TABLE" that way it will always have some data to run with. The issue is that it would create a fake entry and the report would be created with "1 transaction" even if it's an empty one, that's no good for me.

Answer (score 0):

A full answer is hard with the information provided but first of all you have to make clear what you want to see when there are 0 records selected and how the SQL results needs to look like.

One idea could be using a union all SQL statement with the dummy SQL you already described as second SQL in the UNION ALL.

To retrieve only the one or the other I suggest following structure (or something similar)

```
with temp as (
select 'original' as text, 1 as id
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
  where 1 = 1
 union all
select 'fallback' as text, 2 as id
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select * from temp
where id = (select min(id) from temp)
```

The fist part of the UNION AL is the origina statement and the fallback statement is only selected / returned if the first one does not return anything.

The Second statemnt should hold the data you need in case nothing is retuned from the source. You could also use some DataStage logic in addition to this (whenever ID = 2)

Hope this helps